# Should I get shocked? If not, why?

Tags: voltage

Let say they are two different closed circuit. One circuit uses 400 V and another uses 12 V. Let say I touch the positive terminal of 400 V circuit and the negative terminal of 12 V circuit. Should I get shocked because I myself can be considered as some wiring although I have some resistance?

Comment: Voltage is always relative to something. Ground, the opposite terminal of an isolated transformer, the opposite terminal of a battery, etc. In theory, if you had a battery on both circuits, I don't think you would be shocked, since current can't pass since there isn't a return path through a common ground.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, you are right according to my source but I am still confused. As long as there is voltage difference, the curretn should flow. Let say I connect the postive of 400 V circuit and the negatvie of 12V circuit. You mean the current won't flow from 400V to 12V circuit becase they don't have a common ground? Does common ground matter?

Comment: Right, current still wouldn't flow in your scenario. Current flows in loops. There isn't necessarily a voltage difference in your scenario either, because there is only one wire of contact. Wires ideally do not have a voltage across them, so it must all be at the same voltage on the whole wire.

Comment: @SangYunLee, `As long as there is voltage difference` ..... there is a voltage difference only if you have a common reference point ...... your circuit has no common reference point, therefore there is no voltage difference

Answer (score 8):

Let's draw the schematics for a few possible scenarios. The ammeter in the schematics represents your body and its resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9gOlW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*

> Let say I touch the positive terminal of 400 V circuit and the negative terminal of 12 V circuit. Should I get shocked ...?

It depends.

- In Figure 1a both circuits are floating with respect to ground and to each other. In theory no current can flow from one to the other.
- In Figure 1b one circuit is grounded but the other isn't. Touching the 400 V grounded circuit would be a really bad idea as any path to earth through your body could cause electrocution. If you were perfectly insulated then no current would flow because there is no return path to the 400 V negative.
- In Figure 1c both circuits are grounded so touching +400 V and the negative of the 12 V is, effectively, touching both terminals of the 400 V supply. Electrocution is likely.

All of the examples are using DC. When AC is involved you have to take capacitive coupling between each circuit and ground and between the human body and ground. This can be high enough to allow dangerous current to flow.

Comment: I think it might be worth noting that the ammeter in your examples represents the unfortunate individual who is connecting themselves between these 2 voltage sources.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Done.

Comment: +1 Delightful and accurate explanation (with pictures).

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether the two circuits share a common point.

If they are totally isolated from each other, then you would not feel a shock touching any point of one with one hand, and any point of the other with the other.

If the reference points on each circuit share a common ground, then there would be 400-12 = 388 volts between the two point you've touched.

Note that it's quite easy for two circuits that you think are isolated to accidentally share a common ground, perhaps standing with bare feet on a damp floor, or an unnoticed cable plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - you have a weird question but I'll attempt to answer it.

The first thing you need to consider is referencing - if you have two *closed* circuits, where the voltage on the positive terminal isn't referenced to anything other than the negative terminal, then no - you wouldn't get shocked because the 400 volts on the 400 volt circuit's positive terminal is a potential difference of 400 volts with respect to it's own negative terminal and not anything else.

This would be the case in the case that you had - say - two batteries with one producing 400 volts and the other producing 12 volts, you can safely hold the negative of one and the positive of the other without getting shocked. This is because there is no potential difference between the two. INFACT - you can connect the two terminals with a perfectly conductive path and it would just effectively put the two batteries in series.

This changes when you're talking about voltages that are earth referenced, such as those coming out of your wall. Even after rectifying them to be DC voltages - they are still referenced to the earth ground and would have to Galvanically isolated (using a transformer) in order to convert it into an effectively isolated supply. Such supplies are also sometimes called "Floating" supplies because their reference isn't tied down to any level and may be raised to whatever potential you desire.